# Changing a layout depending on a property in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom UI in Android Studio which inherits from LinearLayout. Essentially, it is an edit text with a blue semi-rounded rectangle in it that text can be placed in.

I've added an enum property called `borderSide` which has the values right and left. By default, the border is on the right. What I'm trying to do is have a condition that when borderSide is left, a different layout is selected so the blue semi-rounded rectangle is on the left. Having searched around, I can't see any simple way to do this.

Currently, I have this (apologies if it's a bit messed up, it's on a different machine)

In drawable, I have two files; `supplemental_edittext` and `supplemental_edittext_left`. These are selectors for the different pressed, enabled and focus states and select a drawable. Left means it selects the drawable set for the left side of the edittext. The drawable sets up the border and the rectangle.

The base class (ValidLayout) for the layout inherits LinearLayout, and has a couple of properties for error text. It also inflates a simple layout which contains two text views for a title and the error text. It has an edittext widget in which is added in `@override public void addView` - it looks like this

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
{
    if (child instanced EditText)
    {
         if (editText != null)
             throw new RuntimeException("You can only add 1 child");
         editText = (EditText) child;
         super.addView(child, 1, params);
    }
    else
    {
         super.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

The class I've set the `borderSide` property in (SupplementEditText) extends from the base class and has a method in called `setBorderSide(int side)`. There is a test for edittext (created above) which first checks if it's null and if it isn't sets the background. The code for the change looks like this

```
public void setBorderSide(int side)
{
    if (edittext == null)
       return;
    borderSide = side == 0 ? false : true;
    editText.setBackgroundResource(borderSide ? R.drawable.supplemental_edittext : R.drawable.supplemental_edittext_left);
}
```

The initial call to `setBorderSide` is made in the `Initialise` method.

Together in xml, they work like this

```
<ValidLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vlEditText"
    app:borderSide="left">
    <SupplementEditText
        android:layout_width="match_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sEditText"
        app:supplementTextPosn="end"
        app:supplementText="Hi" />
```

supplementTextPosn and supplementText are two properties in SupplementText that sets the text and text position at the left or right of the EditText inside of the semi rounded rectangle created in the base class

There seems to be two problems though. Firstly (and this is probably the big on), edittext is null. If I remove the check though, the border remains always on the left irrespective of what I set borderSide to.

In AndroidStudio, is there a way to test what is going on and why it's misbehaving and more over, a way to swap from `supplemental_edittext` to `supplemental_edittext_left`

Comment: It's not really clear where the `EditText` is added from. Is that in your custom `View`'s internal layout? Or is it meant to be added in the app layout? Or possibly added programmatically? Also, do you mean to load a different layout depending on `borderSide`'s value, or just set that background drawable differently?

Comment: How are you inflating your LinearLayout custom view? Could you post the code?

Comment: @MikeM. I've modified the original question to include this and how it's used in the xml file

Comment: Sorry, I missed your reply the other day. Anyway, if I'm following you correctly, `setBorderSide()` is being called – directly or indirectly – from a constructor. If that's so, then it's too early to try to use child `View`s added from an app layout. You could move your `setBorderSide()` call to either `addView()`, in the appropriate branch there, or to `onFinishInflate()`, which gets called after a `View` and all of its children are done being inflated from the XML.